# Renting a cab from Manali to Ladakh

Tags: leh-india

I want to rent a cab from Manali to Ladakh this summer but I cannot find anything online where I can book a cab.

Can anyone advise what the best way to reserve a cab is? Can hotels in Manali easily arrange it for us or is it easy to book on the spot in Manali?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly most decent hotels could either help you organise one, or let you know where to.

The distance is around 200km, and a shared taxi would be a reasonably economical way of doing it.

Prices vary, but a quick google search for 'taxi manali ladakh' is very easy to find a bunch of sites that let you organise them, for example - [Discoverledahk.in](http://discoverlehladakh.in/manali_leh_taxi_service.htm) - they have a phone and email contact details.  I suspect, however, that it'd be cheaper to organise once you get there, based on experience travelling in the area and other countries that have shared taxis.